# Dynamic drop down list in PHP and MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have two tables in my database:

- Table 1: `Country => countryid(primary),countryname` and
- Table 2: `State => stateid(primary),countryid(foreign),state`

Now I want to make a drop down list. For example:

- Country `India` (dropdown 1) should show States `Goa`, `UP` and `MP` (dropdown 2)
- Country `Pakistan` (dropdown 1) should show States `Lahore` and `Karachi` (dropdown 2)

I have populated both tables with these values.

Here I am including my code files. I am able to get the first menu working but no values in the second menu. I want the second menu to change instantly when the value selected in the first menu is changed (not just when the page is loaded).

**index.php**

```
<?php 
include('config.php'); 
$query_parent = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM country") or die("Query failed: ".mysql_error());

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Dependent DropDown List</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#countryname").change(function() {
        $(this).after('<div id="loader"><img src="img/loading.gif" alt="loading subcategory" /></div>');
        $.get('loadsubcat.php?countryid=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
            $("#stateid").html(data);
            $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }); 
    });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="get">
    <label for="category">Parent Category</label>
    <select name="countryname" id="countryname">
        <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_parent)): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['countryid']; ?>"><?php echo $row['countryname']; ?></option>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </select>
    <br/><br/>

    <label>Sub Category</label>
<select name="state" id="stateid"></select>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**config.php**

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('login');

?>
```

**loadsubcat.php**

```
<?php     
include('config.php');

$countryid = $_GET['countryid'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM state WHERE countryid = {$countryid}");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "<option value='$row['stateid']'>$row['state']</option>";
}

?>
```

I am not able to figure out my problem. Also I have not done PHP before. This is the first time I am learning and that too with this project, so forgive me if I made disastrous mistakes.

Comment: you might want to look into ajax call

Comment: @j.Doe can you please explain the same in detail?

Comment: see here.i think this works for you http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_database.asp

Comment: @j.Doe Actually this thing I am able to do,selecting an option from a list and displaying its info,i am not able to get menu 2 list

Answer (score 0):

Here you are sending the country id with key name `countryname`:

```
$.get('loadsubcat.php?countryname=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
```

But on your PHP file, you are trying to get the value by using `countryid`:

```
$countryid = $_GET['countryid'];
```

Change and make it same for both. It will work!

**UPDATE:**

```
$("#state").html(data);
```

Here you are referring `state` but on your HTML, you are using `stateid`.

```
<select name="state" id="stateid"></select>
```

Comment: So what should i change? i did but no change in output

Comment: change `$("#state").html(data);` to `$("#stateid").html(data);`

Comment: what does it say or what's the output on your console?

Comment: there in no options showing in 2nd Menu,this is the problem

Comment: Can I uplaod a file and share with you?

Comment: you should have `id="state"` if you are using `$("#state").html(data);` if not then the ajax call won't find where it wants to paste the data

Answer (score 0):

What Muhammad Sumon Molla Selim said is correct and there is one more mistake in loadsubcat.php

you need to change, echoing options statement

### From:

```
echo "<option value='$row['stateid']'>$row['state']</option>";
```

### To:

```
echo "<option value=".$row['stateid'].">".$row['statename']."</option>";
```

Then second dropdown will get states based on change in coutries dropdown.

when I excecuted your code in my local machine I was not getting data. The mistake you did was you are not concatinating the strings and variables properly.

Comment: did it ran correctly on your system?because in mine there is no option in the second drop down list.

Comment: and there is no attribute such as "statename" .Its only state which has the names of states.

Comment: Hey @ArnavRay, yes it ran in my system correctly. I got options for second dropdown on change in first dropdown and in my database table, I've named 'state as statename', but that is not a big problem. Because of *wrong* string concatination, your loadsubcat.php is showing error, that's the reason, even jQuery-Ajax request sent successfully, because of that error in php you are not getting data back. That's it. I hope above solution has worked for you :-)